# Group by month and order the dates on Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query

```php
$months = \App\DATA::select(
    DB::raw('sum(order_value) as `sums`'),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months")
)
    ->where("created_at", ">", \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))
    ->groupBy('months')
    ->get();
```

that makes a sum of the data for every month in the past 6 months. The problem is that it is outputting the dates in alphabetical order.

```
August 2019
July 2019
June 2019
May 2019
November 2019
October 2019
September 2019
```

I cannot order it with a `orderBy`:

```
->orderBy('created_at')
```

due to the following problem

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

How can I order it by date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with `max` function and  `->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')`.

```
$months = \App\DATA::select(
       DB::raw('sum(order_value) as `sums`'),
       DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months"),
       DB::raw('max(created_at) as createdAt')
)
      ->where("created_at", ">", \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))
      ->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      ->groupBy('months')
      ->get();
```

Comment: The potential reporting problem here is that you are selecting a new column which the OP's initial query did not have.

Comment: Thank you! This only worked when the `orderBy` was changed to  `createdAt` instead of `created_at`.

Answer (score 0):

Just order your data by `created_at`:

```php
$months = \App\DATA::select(
    DB::raw('ANY_VALUE(created_at) AS created_at')
    DB::raw('sum(order_value) as `sums`'),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months")
)
    ->where("created_at", ">", \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->groupBy('months')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It cannot be ordered in this way if its being grouped. `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`

Comment: try to add `created_at` in select. i've edited my answer