# Datatable order by Month and Year

Tags: php, laravel

Can i set datatable order by Month and Year ( where i get the data as "October 2021",...."February 2022" ). Refer the attached image for details

This is my code in controller where i get data .

```
 $fiveexpdata = Dairyexpense::select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(expensesdate, "%M %Y") as "month_name",SUM(amount) as "amount"'))
          ->whereBetween('expensesdate', [Carbon::now()->subMonth(6),Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])
          ->groupBy('month_name')
          ->get()
          ->toArray();
```

After Sending the same in datatable, it shows data in
Oct 2021
Nov 2021
Dec 2021
Jan 2022
Feb 2022
March 2022

Where as i required the same in
March 2022
Feb 2022
Jan 2022
Dec 2021
Nov 2021
Oct 2021

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like said in this :

[Group by month and order the dates on Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766526/group-by-month-and-order-the-dates-on-laravel-eloquent)

Do you try do add that ?

```
  ->DB::raw('max(expensesdate) as expensesdate')
  ->orderBy('expensesdate', 'desc')
```